# How to populate a select box with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a simple form with a select box i want to populate with data but i'm not understanding how to do.

This is my form:

```
<form name="form">    
 <select name="req_one" style="width:250px;"/> </select>    
</form>
```

This is what i tried in my JS:

```
var name = 'test';
var i = 1;
document.form.req_one =new Option(name, i);
```

This should then result in the equivalent :

```
<option value="1"> Test </option>
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: When do you execute that code? You need to wait until the select is available in the DOM for example wrap it in `window.onload=function() {...}`

Comment: it executes with a window onload yes. :)

Comment: Old question, but I noticed today your select tag is closed too soon with a `/>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your HTML is invalid, you are closing the select tag

Also wait until the select is available in the DOM

Here is an example

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  const name = 'test';
  const value = 1;
  const sel = document.querySelector("[name=req_one]"); // or give it an ID and use document.getElementById("req_one")
  if (sel) {
    sel.options[sel.options.length] = new Option(name, value);
  } else {
    alert("Where did the sel go?");
  }
})
```

```html
<form name="myform">
  <select name="req_one" style="width:250px;"></select>
</form>
```

Comment: I already have windows onload - but will try the suggested code !

Comment: I seem to get undefined req_one =/ not sure why though. Is there a way to check its loaded first with a if statement?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a easy way with jquery .

```
var name = 'test';
var i = 1;
$("select[name='req_one']").append('<option value="'+i+'">'+value+'</option>');
```

I hope you know how to use jquery .

Comment: What makes that easier than my suggestion in plain JS? Unless jQuery is used for other things, it is a waste of framework and does not save any typing

Comment: with this you dont have to call a function on body on load . A very restricted way to use .  It can be implemented with `$(document).ready` function  .  Also i didnt say your answer is wrong . So chill

Comment: I dont like jQuery :) I tough it out making my own functions.

Comment: Of course you need to execute onload! you need to wrap YOUR code in `$(function() {...});`

Comment: @Dave : I guess if you use jquery . it works cross-platform . And with less coding . You can show better output . also you can wrap this code also inside you javascript function . it will work fine .

Comment: I don't plan to ever use jQuery.

Comment: whats this man .  a  negitive vote for giving a right suggestion .

Comment: wasn't me who did it. Although i think it was because the question wasn't jquery specific =/

Comment: @Dave : thats fine . I just meant to give a suggestion thats all . Its totally your call to use it or not .

Answer (score 0):

You made a tiny error. I consolidated your entire code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function l1(){
    var name = 'test';
    var i = 1;
    document.form.req_one.options[0] =new Option(name, i);//you forgot to include .options[0]
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="l1()">
<form name="form">    
 <select name="req_one" style="width:250px;"/> </select>    
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ya i know... just used for an example

Answer (score 0):

You're forgetting to add the newly created `Option` to the select element's list of options:

```
document.form.req_one.options[0] = new Option(name, i);
```

JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/zxT8U/2/

Comment: That would add the SECOND option

Comment: That's what his code is specifying. To change it to the first option, simply replace `var i = 1;` with `var i = 0;` - zero-based indices and all that.

Comment: His code is specifying that his first option should be `<option value="1">Test</option>` of course when we see ``i`, we see an index :)

Comment: Fair point! Code adjusted, although it should be refactored to store a reference to the select element and use `.length` as yours does.